# lucene - most relevant search and sort the results

Tags: lucene

I am trying to make a search page based on the data we have. Here is my code.

```
            SortField sortField = new SortField(TEXT_FIELD_RANK, SortField.Type.INT, true);
        Sort sort = new Sort(sortField);
        Query q = queryParser.parse(useQuery);
        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(q, totalLimit, sort);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;
        log.info("totalResults="+ topDocs.totalHits);
        int index = getStartIndex(start, maxReturn);
        int resultsLength = start * maxReturn;
        if (resultsLength > totalLimit) {
            resultsLength = totalLimit;
        }
        log.info("index:"+ index + "==resultsLength:"+ resultsLength);
        for (int i = index; i < resultsLength; ++i) {

        }
```

Basically, here is my requirement. If there is an exact match, I need to display the exact match. If there is no exact match, I need to sort the results by the field. So i check the exact match inside the for loop.

But it seems to me that it sorts the results no matter what, so even though there is an exact match, it doesn't show up at the first page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You set it to Sort on a field value, not on relevance, so there is no guarantee that the best matches will be on the first page.  You can sort by Relevance first, then on your field value, like:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(SortField.FIELD_SCORE, sortField);
```

If that is what you were looking for.

Otherwise, if you are looking to ignore relevance for anything except a direct match, you could query using a more restrictive (exact matching) query first, getting your exact matches as an entirely separate result set.